# Bootstrap menu with equal menu items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap menu and I want to use the menu items with equal width (using grid). My problem is, I can't add row class between `ul` and `li` elements, but I need something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav col-sm-6">
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: it  would seem to work as is...[http://www.bootply.com/yVLIbzLuyQ](http://www.bootply.com/yVLIbzLuyQ).

Comment: Do you mean same width but in one column? Then col-xs-12

Comment: But we need to put a row between two different cols, because in this case won't fit perfectly. The row class add some negative margin for the element.
http://www.bootply.com/qiuv88zRv1

Answer (score 0):

Like Ted said above, what you have would work.
But it also sounds like you want to add a space or gap between.

If so why not just add...
Make sure you allow in the col-lg-x for the extra width.

```
<style>
.gapit {
    width:1%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    height:50px;
  }
</style>
<li class="col-lg-2"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="gapit"></li>  
<li class="col-lg-2"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="gapit"></li>  
<li class="col-lg-2"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Or if you don't want to do it this way, how about just add some margin to the right like this...

```
<style>
.padit {
    margin-right:1%; 
  }
</style>
<li class="col-lg-2 padit"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="col-lg-2 padit"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="col-lg-2"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```